# Noether comment to Dedekind and Weber's work

Tags: math-history

I am trying to consult Emmy Noether's “Erläuterungen zur vorstehenden Abhandlung”, some sort of epilogue or comment to Richard Dedekind and Heinrich Weber's “Theorie der algebraischen Funktionen einer Veränderlichen”. Dedekind and Weber's work originally appeared in 1882, and Noether added her contribution in her edition of the complete works of Dedekind in 1930.
 Could anyone provide me with a link, copy of the text, whatever? I can read German, so the original version should no scare me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example, I came across this quotation, and I am just not able to figure out whether it is due to Dedekind and Weber themselves or to Noether: “Für den allgemeinen Fall, welcher sich zu dem eben genannten ähnlich verhält, wie der Fall de allgemeinsten algebraischen Zahlen zu demjenigen der rationalen Zahlen, wiesen die mit bestem Erfolge in der Zahlentheorie angewandten Methoden, die sich an Kummers Schöpfung der idealen Zahlen anschlieen, und der Übertragung auf die Theorie der Funktionen fähig sind, auf den richtigen Weg.”

Comment: Ok, I have just checked and the quotation is from Dedekind and Weber. I am still waiting for your response regarding Noether, though. :)

Comment: Apparently what I am looking for is on page 350 of Fricke, Noether and Ore's edition of Dedekind's complete works (volume 1, I think, though not 100 % sure of that). Could some one provide me that page? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry any longer. I have just found it. In case you were interested: 
http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/loader/img/?PPN=PPN235691801&DMDID=DMDLOG_0023&LOGID=LOG_0023&PHYSID=PHYS_0357